# translate makes an empty area on sides

Tags: css

I have `<div class="scrollable">` that have this css: `overflow: scroll;`
plus I have `<div class="line1"></div>` that must not add any scroll to `<div class="scrollable">`(because I want to translate `<div class="line1"></div>` later). So I make an outer div with `overflow:hidden`.
But when I translate it(blue box)(I made an animation for translating) it makes white area on the left side that I do not want it (I want it like the right side)
how to fix or change this.
Thanks in advance

```css
.scrollable {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.no-scroll {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.line1 {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: wave 4s 0.1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(360deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(-360deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
  <div class="no-scroll">
    <div class="line1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an element and you must to stretch the element and control it by percent(%) instead pixel.

Ex :
width: 120%;
right : -40% or -40px;

Answer (score 2):

Your .line1 (wave) div is not centred, that's why you see the blank space on the left when the animation moves the object to the right. Since the width is 500px you can center it by applying `margin-left: -250px`. This should fix the problem. See example below.

```css
.scrollable {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.no-scroll {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.line1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: wave 4s 0.1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(360deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(-360deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 0) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="inner-container"></div>
    <div class="no-scroll">
      <div class="line1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```